# verify gunzip decompression

Tags: verification, data-integrity, gunzip

I am working with large datasets that I have concatenated using: `cat file1.fasta.gz file2.fasta.gz > newfile.fasta.gz`

Then I unzip newfile using: `gunzip newfile.fasta.gz`, to work with it in some bioinformatics software. The gunzip takes forever and I leave the computer and come back later.

I am worried that the process may have failed at some point, leaving a partial file. Is there any way to ascertain that `newfile.fasta` contains the complete decompressed content of `newfile.fasta.gz`?

inb4: "don't leave your computer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine. If you're worried, then you could just check the file size:
newfile.fasta.gz should be the size of file1.fasta.gz + file2.fasta.gz.

Since it looks like you've already unzipped the new file, you could double check the number of sequence entries in each fasta file.

```
$ gunzip -c file1.fasta.gz | grep -c '^>'
$ gunzip -c file2.fasta.gz | grep -c '^>'
$ grep -c '^>' newfile.fasta
```

or if you could just substitute the "grep -c '^>'" for wc.